# JS TinyMCE change width and heigth of pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I`m using tinymce plugin, and I have a little problem.
In the TOOLS tab there is source button (here is a link http://www.tinymce.com/). When I click on it, new pop-up window appear.
So, the problem is that for some monitors, this window is too big, because width and height set in px.
Is there some way to change this properties from size in px to percent? For example from width:640px and height:630px (as in example) to width:52% and height:75%

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the textarea for TinyMCE in a div and style it to your requirement

For Example:

```
<style>
#div
{
    width : 50% !important;
}
</style>


<div id="div">
<textarea>text</textarea>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.